# Bootstrap input box - smaller width required

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, inputbox

I know this has been asked before but I the answers don't seem to work for me.
I am looking to decrease the size of my textbox and line it up beside a select and some text.
Here is my code.

```
<div class="controls">
  <div class="btn-group">   
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <input type="checkbox" name="blah" value="true">
      Title
      <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>8</option>
      </select>
      <input class="form-control col-xs-1" placeholder="x" type="text" required="required">this should be beside the textbox. I also want the textbox to be small. One character small.
    </label> 
  </div>                                        
</div>
```

Also in bootply.
http://www.bootply.com/NePcbYQqfm

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="controls">
 <div class="btn-group col-xs-4">   
 <label class="btn btn-default">
  <input name="blah" value="true" type="checkbox">
  Title
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>8</option>
  </select>
  </label> 


  <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="x" required="required" type="text">this should be beside the textbox. I also want the textbox to be small. One character small.
 </div>
</div>
```

It will work.